# disallow the passing of generic type on function call

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to define the following function:

```
  function sequence<T = number>(fn: (x: number) => T = (x => x) ) {
    return ((i: number) => () => fn(i++))(0)
  }
```

I'm getting the following complaint from the compiler:

```
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  'number' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{}'
```

However, the type inference just works fine:

```
const seq = sequence() // return type: () => number
const seq2 = sequence(x => `${x}`) // return type: () => string
```

Do you know how to get rid of this error while keeping the type inference?

EDIT: Investigating a little more about the error, I found this happens because I could call `sequence` as follows:

```
const seq3 = sequence<string>() // return type: () => string
```

what is effectively an error because by default `sequence` has `() => number` as return type.

Is there a way to disallow the third example?

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution, probably not the most elegant one:

```
function sequence(): () => number
function sequence<T>(fn: (x: number) => T): () => T

function sequence<T>(fn?: (x: number) => T) {
  if (fn) return ((i: number) => () => fn(i++))(0);
  return ((i: number) => () => i++)(0);
}
```

Essentially, you have to overload the function to disambiguate each case.